# Reflection in Struts 2

Tags: java, reflection, struts2, ognl, private-members

I have an action class which has approximately 30 variables. Getters and setters for these fields mess up my code and adds unnecessary lines. Is there a way to reflect all the `private` fields and make them "visible" for Struts?

Comment: Where do you want to use this functionality? On the presentation layer (screens)?

Comment: Yes @Buhake Sindi. Struts seems to have access to variables only through getters and setters, but that's not good practice

Comment: @VladMatvei It *is* a good practice to use getters and setters in Java Beans, but your question is extra ordinal +1.

Comment: Thank you Roman! I think ORM works through REFLECTION to access private fields of a class. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: pity point for having to use struts in 2014.

Comment: @VladMatvei ORM uses Introspection to access property from Java Beans. Google it! It's built in the Java SDK.

Comment: @jangroth Struts 1.x and Struts 2.x are 2 **completely** different frameworks, each with their own architecture. Struts 1 is MVC based while Struts 2 is component based (like JSF).

Comment: @Buhake Sindi - sorry mate, did not want to start a flame war about this. I'm sure it's a great framework - I guess it just wasn't for me when I had to use it.

Comment: @jangroth S2 is essentially the same as Spring MVC with some differences.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I wouldn't really say that S2 is like JSF in any real sense.

Comment: @DaveNewton absolutely. Sorry, in fact, JSF is purely event based component framework while Struts 2 is MVC based component framework.

Comment: @DaveNewton Spring MVC is purely MVC framework, of which Struts2 is MVC Component based framework.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry, I read it late last night and I thought it said "Par OF the course." :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the wrong approach to me.

Getters and setters are pretty fundamental in Java's concept of OO and encapsulation. If you don't like *writing* getters and setters either use a framework like Lombok (http://projectlombok.org/index.html), or choose a different language, eg Gradle.

Most - if not all - Java code uses them, so maybe your perception that they mess up the code is slightly wrong. A good IDE should help you get that out of the way.

Oh, and Reflection adds a massive performance overhead and is totally not meant to short-circuit access to private members.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need getters and setters for OGNL to work. But don't do that.

If your concern is the "overhead" of a larger class then create an object that encapsulates view state and expose only that. You could also do this through the `ModelDriven` interface; some caveats apply.

Getters and setters are par for the course in Java. Get used to it. Use an IDE that automatically folds simple `getXxx`/`setXxx` methods. Start using the presenter pattern to encapsulate view state and use them as a translation layer between the web and your business domain objects.

Comment: My entities are immutable and I guess ModelDriven interface will not work for me. But I could write a DTO object, would that be a good approach?